# How to reach the destination which is after 300 routers

Tags: routing, router

One my senior in my office asked me this question.
I have a source at R1 and my destination is after 300 routers R300. Will my packet reach my destination ?

Host A -->R1-R2-R3-.....R300-->Host B

1. Is this a question valid ?
2. If Yes, then how ?
3. Can I increase my TTL more than 255 ? (I believe this is not possible)

Looking for an answer..

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A - Look at [RFC0791](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0791.txt)
B - Search for the IP headers definition and length
C - draw your own conclusions

Note that in real world there's no path as long as 300 hops. If I remember correctly the longest path that exists on the Internet is between 30 & 40 hops.

Comment: If, for some reason, one did have a path longer than 255 hops, one would have to use tunneling or maybe MPLS/VPLS or similar. I think that before we get to that point we'll have to think deploy protocols that are more resistant to timeouts over interplanetary or interstellar distances.